# What to present to the rabbi

Tags: rabbis, gifts

My friend is going to meet rabbi, to talk about house management, and she wants to bring some present to him. What you would present to the rabbi, and what you should not to? Please explain why.

Comment: Deele, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around the site and find other information that is also of interest to you, perhaps including our 36 other [tag:gifts] questions.

Comment: @IsaacMoses already checked them and they contain unrelated information to this question, or I do not understand words there are used...

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to bring a present in the first place, but it is a kind gesture. Rabbis are paid to serve their congregants and community for a variety of reasons relating to philosophy, halacha, et cetera.

If you could give a price range, this question can be better answered; however, I'll just throw a general answer out in the open. You can always buy the [rav](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/593) a bottle of wine. I recommend a [kosher merlot](http://www.kosherwine.com/cgi-bin/ProductInfo.asp?WineID=11799&SavedSearch=Y). The merlot hyperlinked is pretty nice, sold at a reasonable price, and serves as a nice gift. I answer wine because it's so versatile. The rabbi can use it for kiddush at the shul, open it up with his family during Shabbos dinner, or simply use it for havdalah and officially end Shabbat with a nice taste.

Comment: Could you improve your answer, with something, that should not be presented or is considered as a rude gesture.

Comment: Why merlot, specifically?

Comment: I would not recommend wine (or any food item) without clarifying that it must be Kosher.

Comment: It's a nice wine, but it's not too expensive. That's why.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend wine. It has its own stringencies not found in other products. I don't know how much the person giving knows about Kashrus and Hashgacha intricacies, so the gift may end up being unused.

Comment: I think it needs to be emphasized that "paying the rabbi" is not a sacrament nor any sort of Jewish ritual. If you want to get him a gift because he's helpful go ahead.

Comment: Well that's why hechshers exist, so you don't need to know about the stringent halacha to keep kashruth. Just get any wine with an OU and most people will accept it.