# How do I give pidyon?

Tags: money, tzedakah-charity, chasidut-hasidism, social-convention, chassidic-rebbe

I am soon to visit a chasidic rebbe for a one-on-one meeting, for almost the first time in my life. I understand it is both appropriate and customary to (if feasible) leave "*pidyon*" — that is, money or a check made payable to the rebbe's congregation or organization. Do I give the check to the rebbe? give it to his *gabay* (secretary/gatekeeper)? leave it on the rebbe's desk? or what? Do I do so before (or at the start of) my meeting? after (or at the end)? or when? Any further details will be appreciated also.

Comment: every place has different protocol I believe

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33708/759

Answer (score 1):

Since each rabbi has a different protocol, the wisest thing to do is to ask the Gabbai "how is it done here?".